# How can I create a discrete slider in react-native (iOS)?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a slider component in my react-native app that is nicely restricted to discrete values from 1-5 using the minimum/maximumValue properties and some rounding in onValueChange:

```
<View>
    <Text style={styles.text} >
      {this.state.value}
    </Text>
    <SliderIOS
      ref='slider'
      style={styles.slider}
      value={1}
      minimumValue={1}
      maximumValue={5}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
        this.setState({
          value: Math.round(value)
        });
      }}
    />
</View>
```

What I would like is for the slider handle button to snap to the discrete positions 1,2,3,4,5 rather than move continuously along the slider. Hints appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

For future reference: SliderIOS has been deprecated in the meantime and one should use the Slider component. `<Slider>` comes with a step attribute:

> Step value of the slider. The value should be between 0 and (maximumValue - minimumValue). Default value is 0.

So the solution to the specific question would be to simply set

```
<Slider
    step={1}
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

you're almost there but in the docs of [SliderIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sliderios.html) it says:

> **value** number
>
> Initial value of the slider. The value should be between minimumValue
>   and maximumValue, which default to 0 and 1 respectively. Default value
>   is 0.
>
> This is not a *controlled component*, e.g. if you don't update the
>   value, the component won't be reset to its inital value.

Therefore, it's not possible to control the behavior of the native slider in the way you want it to work.

## Solution using another component

However, there is a JavaScript version of the [`<Slider>` component](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider) which let's you do it. Since it uses some of the props SliderIOS has, you can easily replace it. Just load the npm module, require it and change `<SliderIOS>` to `<Slider>`. Now you need to make some adjustments to your current code:

1. The property `value` of the component should reference a variable which can be changed by your code. You can use `getInitialState` to have a default value.
2. Add your callback function used for `onValueChange` to `onSlidingComplete`. Otherwise you could still have values in between when you release the slider.
3. I used sliderValue instead of value to make it clearer.

`

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        sliderValue: 1
    }
},

onSliderValueChange(value) {
     this.setState({
         sliderValue: Math.round(value)
     });
},

render() {
  return(
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.text} >
          {this.state.sliderValue}
        </Text>
        <Slider
          ref='slider'
          style={styles.slider}
          value={this.state.sliderValue}
          minimumValue={1}
          maximumValue={5}
          onValueChange={this.onSliderValueChange}
          onSlidingComplete={this.onSliderValueChange}
        />
    </View> 
  )
}
```

`

*I didn't check my last version the code but it should work like that.*

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try it out this evening and mark it accordingly.